# Xcode 5 invalid image path error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Im relatively new to programming and am just in the process of uploading my first app to the app store however i am getting the following error message which i just can't figure out / fix. I have looked everywhere online for a solution but as yet, no luck. Please can someone help? I am using Xcode 5:
Error:

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon40x40'" at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

This really doesn't mean anything to me as i have tried all the usual asset catalogue stuff / looked at my p-list.

Comment: Xcode is looking for image which is not where it should be. Maybe you've delated image from folder or didn't copy it at all?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i thought that so thought i would add an icon in with the exact name that the system seems to be looking for however i do not know where to locate this new file for the system to be able to find it. do you have any idea based on the stated path?

Comment: So if you say that you provide everything it's impossible that this still is not working for you. Try removing all icons from assets and load them one more time just by draging them and dropping in Xcode.

Comment: ok, i have tried what you suggest and something strange is happening (maybe indicative of my error?).I removed all images from the supporting files and re-added them, however some won't go in the supporting files folder now as i am getting an error message stating that a file with that name already exists (however i can't see them in there anywhere!).how odd!

Comment: It really is odd... But you don't have to copy those images into supporting files folder. You just have to paste them in those icon squares! Just like in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need an App Icon.

If you created the project in Xcode 5 then there should be a catalogue called Images.xcassets where you should place the icons of the correct sizes for your app.

I have added a screenshot of my app as an example of what I am talking about:

[image: Image Catalogue]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used Xcode 5 and i have completed all icons in the images.xcassets section but still get this error message relating to 'AppIcon40x40'…I have no idea whats causing this!

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error. First I thought that the images where not correct (I found one with 144 dpi), but the error showed up again.

Just search for the exact name "AppIcon40x40" in the whole project using Shift+Cmd+F. I have seen it referenced in a plist file under another key. There you have to change the names to the appropriate ones.